# Using an HTML select in form

Tags: html, css

For some reason I cannot get the Select option to go inline with the choose file, inside the share-actions-left div. What am I doing wrong?

http://jsfiddle.net/Ey9vA/

Thanks

Comment: The input is in a div which the select isn't

Comment: the select is outside of the `#share-action` div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`#share-action` should be inline block

```
#share-action {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you're looking to to would be handled by making the elements inline block similar to what @Daniil is saying. To get your code to work as is add this

```
#share-actions-left *{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following CSS to get the select on the same line as the upload button:

```
#share-action{float: left;}
```